# FL_Charts bottomtitle overlapping each other on small screens. How to fix?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, fl-chart

I'm new to flutter and am having issues with flutter FL_Charts. I've looked at their documentation and tried change the bottomTiles but the txt will overlap one another on small screens.

Ideally, I would want to add horizontal scroll as I'll be inserting data dynamically.

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs5D0.png)

**My Current Code:**

```
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';

class WaterUsageBarChart extends StatefulWidget {
  WaterUsageBarChart({super.key});

  final Color? leftBarColor = Colors.yellow[200];
  final Color? rightBarColor = Colors.red[200];
  final Color? avgColor = Colors.orange;

  @override
  State<WaterUsageBarChart> createState() => _WaterUsageBarChartState();
}

class _WaterUsageBarChartState extends State<WaterUsageBarChart> {
  final double width = 7;

  late List<BarChartGroupData> rawBarGroups;
  late List<BarChartGroupData> showingBarGroups;

  int touchedGroupIndex = -1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //* Amount of bar in chart
    //* makeGroupData(Grouping, Bar1, Bar2)
    final barGroup1 = makeGroupData(0, 0, 2);
    final barGroup2 = makeGroupData(1, 20, 20);
    final barGroup3 = makeGroupData(2, 5, 5);
    final barGroup4 = makeGroupData(3, 5, 16);
    final barGroup5 = makeGroupData(4, 7, 6);
    final barGroup6 = makeGroupData(5, 1000, 900);
    final barGroup7 = makeGroupData(6, 10, 1.5);

    final items = [
      barGroup1,
      barGroup2,
      barGroup3,
      barGroup4,
      barGroup5,
      barGroup6,
      barGroup7,
    ];

    rawBarGroups = items;

    showingBarGroups = rawBarGroups;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              // makeTransactionsIcon(),
              const Icon(Icons.water_drop_rounded, color: Colors.white),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 38,
              ),
              Column(
                children: const [
                  Text(
                    'Average Water Usage',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'per month',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff77839a),
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 38,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: BarChart(
                  BarChartData(
                    maxY: 5000,
                    barTouchData: BarTouchData(
                      touchTooltipData: BarTouchTooltipData(
                        tooltipBgColor: Colors.grey,
                        getTooltipItem: (a, b, c, d) => null,
                      ),
                      touchCallback: (FlTouchEvent event, response) {
                        if (response == null || response.spot == null) {
                          setState(() {
                            touchedGroupIndex = -1;
                            showingBarGroups = List.of(rawBarGroups);
                          });
                          return;
                        }
              
                        touchedGroupIndex = response.spot!.touchedBarGroupIndex;
              
                        setState(() {
                          if (!event.isInterestedForInteractions) {
                            touchedGroupIndex = -1;
                            showingBarGroups = List.of(rawBarGroups);
                            return;
                          }
                          showingBarGroups = List.of(rawBarGroups);
                          if (touchedGroupIndex != -1) {
                            var sum = 0.0;
                            for (final rod
                                in showingBarGroups[touchedGroupIndex].barRods) {
                              sum += rod.toY;
                            }
                            final avg = sum /
                                showingBarGroups[touchedGroupIndex]
                                    .barRods
                                    .length;
              
                            showingBarGroups[touchedGroupIndex] =
                                showingBarGroups[touchedGroupIndex].copyWith(
                              barRods: showingBarGroups[touchedGroupIndex]
                                  .barRods
                                  .map((rod) {
                                return rod.copyWith(
                                    toY: avg, color: widget.avgColor);
                              }).toList(),
                            );
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                      show: true,
                      rightTitles: AxisTitles(
                        sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
                      ),
                      topTitles: AxisTitles(
                        sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
                      ),
                      bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                        sideTitles: SideTitles(
                          showTitles: true,
                          getTitlesWidget: bottomTitles,
                          reservedSize: 42,
                        ),
                      ),
                      leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                        sideTitles: SideTitles(
                          showTitles: true,
                          reservedSize: 28,
                          interval: 1,
                          getTitlesWidget: leftTitles,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    borderData: FlBorderData(
                      show: false,
                    ),
                    barGroups: showingBarGroups,
                    gridData: FlGridData(show: false),
                  ),
                ),
            ),
            ),
          // const SizedBox(
          //   height: 12,
          // ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //* Data
  Widget leftTitles(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(
      color: Color(0xff7589a2),
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 14,
    );
    String text;
    if (value == 0) {
      text = '1K';
    } else if (value == 5) {
      text = '5K';
    } else if (value == 5000) {
      text = '5K';
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      space: 0,
      child: Text(text, style: style),
    );
  }

  //* By number of bars created
  Widget bottomTitles(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    //TODO Dynamically create titles from data
    final titles = <String>['22 Feb', '23 Feb', '24 Feb', '25 Feb', '26 Feb', '27 Feb', '28 Feb'];

    final intIndex = value.isFinite ? value.toInt() : 0;
    final title = intIndex >= 0 && intIndex < titles.length ? titles[intIndex] : '';

    final Widget text = Text(
      // titles[value.toInt()], // Original code
      title,
      style: const TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xff7589a2),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 14,
      ),
    );

    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      space: 16, //16 //margin top
      child: text,
    );
  }

  BarChartGroupData makeGroupData(int x, double y1, double y2) {
    return BarChartGroupData(
      barsSpace: 4, //4
      x: x,
      barRods: [
        BarChartRodData(
          toY: y1,
          color: widget.leftBarColor,
          width: width,
        ),
        BarChartRodData(
          toY: y2,
          color: widget.rightBarColor,
          width: width,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**After Adding Horizontal Scroll Widget**
I've tried to add horizontal scroll and it has render issues but I'm unable to solve.
It seem to have render issues. I've also tried to add height: 300 to attempt to solve the Infinity or NaN. Please help thanks.

[HorizontalScroll Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIE8G.png)

**Error:**
═╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following UnsupportedError was thrown building SideTitlesWidget(dirty):
Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt

The relevant error-causing widget was:
SideTitlesWidget

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but..

I ran into your last error with fl_chart:
"SideTitlesWidget(dirty): Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt".

In my case it was solved by an Expanded() around the chart.
Did you miss that somewhere?